# Trying to get an employees computer to join Azure AD but it keeps using his personal account and not the new AAD account

Tags: azure-activedirectory

We're migrating to office 365 from G-Suite. I've added a member to office 365, and joined our domain with that account.

The problem is it will only sign into our comptuer with his personal Password, and not his azure AD password.

He has a personal account (bobby@mycompany.com) and an azure AD account (bobby@mycompany.com) Same email address.

MS has realized this is an issue and has blocked the ability to create personal accounts when there's a AAD account.

what I have done:

1. Create local admin user
2. Upgrade PC to Windows 10 Pro
3. Add his Office 365 account
4. Connect him to the azure AD with his email

Number 4 is where it went weird. It did not accept his office 365 / AAD un/pw. It did however accept his personal UN/PW. After signing in it tells me he's connected to our Azure AD, but when I look at our AzureAD i don't see his device at all.

Is there a way to fix this? I know MS is deep in the weeds trying to solve personal emails and business accounts with the same email address (MS won't allow you to merge them).

Comment: How is the computer currently configured? Is the employee using a fully local account, or a "Microsoft account", within Windows? And are you trying to use a "Microsoft account", or are you trying to use the "Join Azure AD" feature?

Comment: Right now it's a brand new computer.  I put the local admin account on, and then tried to connect to AzureAD. It didn't work with our Office 365 account un/pw but then added his personal live account (same email address).